# innerHTML só faz efeito uma vez, e elementos gerados dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html

Estou a fazer uma experiência em javascript que ao clicar num determinado elemento com uma certa classe vamos adicionar um novo elemento com a mesma classe, sempre que clicar deveria aparecer um novo elemento.

```js
var my_divs = document.getElementsByClassName('my-div');
for (var i = 0; i < my_divs.length; i++) {
    my_divs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
       var next_id = my_divs.length + 1; 
       document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="div' +next_id+ '" class="my-div"></div>';
       //console.log(next_id);
    });
}
```

```css
.my-div {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
.my-div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:red;
}
.my-div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="my-div">

</div>
```

Como se pode ver, funciona, mas só uma vez. Eu até compreendo que o clique na que aparece dinamicamente não faça nada porque o evento não chegou a ser associado à nova div. Mas mesmo assim, porque é que o clique na primeira só faz efeito uma vez? E como faria para obter aquilo que quero? Sempre que clicar em qualquer (`.my_div`), gerada dinamicamente ou não aparecer outra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que `+=` é o mesmo que `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + resto`, ou seja re-escreve todo o HTML e por isso rompe os auscultadores de eventos.

Para fazeres isso funcionar para qualquer elemento (criado depois ou não) precisas de um delegador, e nesse caso podes usar `.appendChild()` ou re-escrever o HTML todo como estavas a fazer. Eu prefiro usar `.appendChild()`, usando `+=` no `body.innerHTML` é violento e pode estragar código em outras partes do DOM.

Exemplo usando delegação:

```js
var ids = 2;
var minhaClasse = 'my-div';
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    if (!el.classList.contains(minhaClasse)) return;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add(minhaClasse);
 div.id = ids++;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
.my-div {
    margin: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="my-div"></div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5pdvxp9q/

Outra maneira mais local seria assim:

```
function addDiv() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add(minhaClasse);
    div.id = ids++;
    div.addEventListener('click', addDiv);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
document.querySelector('.my-div').addEventListener('click', addDiv);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5pdvxp9q/2/

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio. É isto mesmo... Aceito já em poucos mins

Comment: Em vez de reescrever tudo, mais vale só adicionar claro.

Comment: Haa tu adicionas logo o evento à window e só depois especificas o elemento ao certo. É o mesmo que `$(window).on('click', '.my-div', function() { ... })` certo?

Comment: Reparei agora num pequeno erro, no seu... Talvez deva editar, a segunda `div`, a primeira a ser gerada vem com `id=0`, deveria vir com `id=2`

Comment: @Miguel exato, com jQuery seria esse o código de delegação. Juntei mais info à resposta.

Comment: Obrigado. Esclarecido