# Layout input dinamico para upload com galeria

Tags: javascript, arquivo

Olá,

Estou criando um recurso onde o mecanismo deve:

1. escolher uma imagem no input
2. ao realizar o change do input, um novo é criado via js ao lado
3. chegando aí, preciso de ajuda, pq a função só executa no
   primeiro input, e para de funcionar nos demais... Como faço para que a função do change, continue funcionando em todos os inputs?

Coloquei o código completo no jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sb9c32qe/2/

e o trecho do js para ser ajudado, vou colocar aqui tbm:

```
$(".dragNdropUpload_box input").change(function(){                                      

  var create_dragNdropUpload_box =  "<div class='dragNdropUpload_box'>"+
     "<div class='dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout'>"+  
     "<span class='icon far fa-plus-square'></span>"+
     "<span class='text'></span>"+
     "</div><!-- /dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout-->"+
     "<input type='file' name='dragNdropUpload_box[]' />"+
     "</div><!-- /dragNdropUpload_box-->";                                                                                                    


  $(".dragNdropUpload").append(create_dragNdropUpload_box);

  //setTimeout(function(){ 

  var getFileName = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();    
  alert(getFileName);   


  $(this).parent().find(".dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout .text").html(getFileName);

  //}, 1000);                   

});//end change
```

Comment: questões relacionadas que podem te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131216/57220  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100365/57220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como os elementos seguintes são dinâmicos, você precisa realizar o **bind** do handler **change** no **document**.

Assim, ao invés de utilizar 
**$(".dragNdropUpload_box input").change(function(){ ...**

Utilize **$(document).on("change", ".dragNdropUpload_box input", (function(){ ...**

Altere para:

```js
$(document).on("change", ".dragNdropUpload_box input", (function(){              
 var create_dragNdropUpload_box =  "<div class='dragNdropUpload_box'>"+
"<div class='dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout'>"+
"<span class='icon far fa-plus-square'></span>"+
"<span class='text'></span>"+
"</div><!-- /dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout-->"+
"<input type='file' name='dragNdropUpload_box[]' />"+
"</div><!--/dragNdropUpload_box-->";                            
                      
 $(".dragNdropUpload").append(create_dragNdropUpload_box);
 var getFileName = $(this).val().split('\\').pop(); 
 $(this).parent().find(".dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout .text").html(getFileName);     
}));
```

```css
body{
 text-align:center;
}
.dragNdropUpload{
 display:inline-block;
 width:1000px;
 max-width:95%;
 margin:10% 0 0 0;
 padding:20px 0 20px 0;
 border:0px solid #c9ceda;  
}
.dragNdropUpload_box{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 margin:0 20px 0 0;
 border:2px dashed #c9ceda;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.dragNdropUpload_box:hover{
 border:2px dashed #a5adbd; 
}
.dragNdropUpload_box:hover .dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout .icon{
 color:#a5adbd;
}
.dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout{
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:transparent; 
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 z-index:1;
}
.dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout span{
 display:inline-block;
}
.dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout .icon{
 display:inline-block;
 font-size:68px;
 margin:32% 0 0 0;
 color:#c9ceda; 
}
.dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout .text{
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 padding:5px 0 15px 0;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family:arial;
 color:#adb5c7;
}
.dragNdropUpload_box input{
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
 background-color:#eee;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 z-index:1;
 opacity:0;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dragNdropUpload">
 
 <div class="dragNdropUpload_box">
  <div class="dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout">
   <span class="icon far fa-plus-square"></span>
   <span class="text"></span>
  </div><!-- /dragNdropUpload_box_input_layout-->  
  <input type="file" name="dragNdropUpload_box[]" />  
 </div><!-- /dragNdropUpload_box-->
 
</div><!-- /dragNdropUpload-->
```

Comment: Perfeito, era isso mesmo @Allan ! resolveu... https://jsfiddle.net/sb9c32qe/12/